# Correct way to configure Bridge network in centos

Tags: linux, networking, centos, bridge, centos-6

I am trying to configure bridge network in the HP server. I dont have console access. I am connected using ssh to the server remotely. 
The configuration files have been placed in the proper location /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts

```
cat ifcfg-eth0 
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
IPV6INIT=no
USERCTL=no
BRIDGE=br0

cat ifcfg-br0
DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=IP of the server
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
```

When I restart the network service after configuring this
`/etc/init.d/network restart`, I am getting disconnected from the terminal.
What is the proper way to do this configuration?

The above configuration works perfectly on the virtualbox setup, but when I try to implement the same to a physical server, it fails to set up the bridge.

I am using Centos 6.8 OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out on this.

During the bridge configuration,

- For bridge interface (br0) you need to mention the actual Hardware
  Address, disable NetworkManager control and enable the onboot.
- For ethernet interface (eth0), you need to mention a different 
  Hardware Address (last digit can be changed), disable NetworkManager 
  control and enable the onboot.

Example configuration

```
ifcfg-br0
=========
DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
HWADRESS=00:1C:23:59:5A:92
IPADDR=192.168.1.109
#NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
#BOOTPROTO=dhcp
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DELAY=0

ifcfg-eth0
==========
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
HWADRESS=00:1C:23:59:5A:93
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BRIDGE=br0
```

you can create a shell script and run it in nohup mode.

```
$ echo  "service network restart" > restart_network.sh
$ chmod u+x restart_network.sh
$ nohup ./restart_network.sh &
```

I was able to configure the bridge network on multiple physical servers without the network getting disconnected. I did not have console or physical access to server, but used only remote connection via ssh.